# How to check if check box is checked with change listener

Tags: javascript, yui, yui3

I am trying to check if a check box is checked and show an element on the page if it is checked.

This is my function:

```
function checkedTechSolutions(){    
    Y.one('#techsol input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function (e) {
        var target = e.currentTarget,
        techSBox = Y.one('#techsolutions');
        if (target.get('checked')){ 
            techSBox.show();
        } else techSBox.hide();
    }
}
```

This is my css:

```
#techsolutions {width: 380px; height: 100px; background-color:#cee4f2; display: none;}
#techsolutions .box {text-align: center;}
```

This is my html:

```
<div id="techsolutions">

    <div class=box>
    <label for="TypeOfTS">Tech Solutions: </label>
    <select name="techSolutionsDrop">
        <option value="techServices">Choose your services </option>
    </select>
    </div>  

</div>
```

Comment: It would be easier if you posted a link to code in jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some notes:

- Your example lacked the checkbox in `#techsol`
- Was `checkedTechSolutions` ever called? You do not need a document ready type event to attach a listener to a checkbox when using YUI.
- Use **css classes** to change visuals like this. It is easier to understand and cleaner.

Take a look at the full solution in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jgdx/AxUMD/)

Comment: Woops sorry I forgot to add my checkbox html code. It was a bit before the div.

Comment: Thankyou. I also have another question. How can i get the checkbox, when checked be displayed in the blue box. I realise that a child class cannot be hidden while the parent class is, so how can I achive this?

Comment: Move the `hidden` class, and update the JS like so: http://jsfiddle.net/jgdx/AxUMD/2/

Comment: Thats good, but I also want the blue box to appear and dissapear with the dropdown.: 

so if i have a <div> with the blue box></div> and then a 
<div> with the check box </div>
<div> with the drop down </div>

and then, the blue box and the drop down are hidden when the checkbox is unchecked and when checked, the bluebox and drop down appear but the checkbox is within the blue box.

how can i do this using css or do I need to js it?

thanks

Comment: You could 1) color a div behind both elements blue IF the checkbox is checked or b) use absolute positioning on the checkbox. There are probably other ways too, so experiment a little. :)

Comment: This is what ive added http://jsfiddle.net/AxUMD/12/ - So the background colour is actually white but when the check box is checked, it should change to blue. Its not actually working, but to mu understanding it should. Please explain to me why it is not working, am I missing something? Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: I have decided to do it like this http://jsfiddle.net/AxUMD/54/ .
Please can you tell me whats causing the error. Thanks

Comment: Ok I have achieved this another way: http://jsfiddle.net/AxUMD/98/ Thank you so much for your help.